# Route all subdomains except one in Nginx configuration

Tags: linux, nginx

How do I send all requests for `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` to the root `/directoryA` except for the subdomain `specific.domain.com` which needs to go to the root `/directoryB`.

`www.domain.com` is already redirected to `domain.com` and should stay that way if possible.

Comment: Please clarify if you actually want to serve request for *.domain.com. Though (IMHO) that is not recommended. You can check out this [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/462852/138643) regarding wild card domain setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is create different `server` section with different server name

```
server {
  server_name domain.com

  root /directoryA

  ... other options ...

}

server {
  server_name specific.domain.com

  root /directoryB

  ... other options ...

}
```

No section is created for www.domain.com as it is already redirected. (Or www.domain.com will have its own server section to handle the redirection).